# How to open the folder of a file that is not in any of the projects?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a file generated by a tool. The file is not in any of the projects, therefore cannot be located in the solution explorer. I want to rename the file. This is not possible through the right-mouse-button menu of an item in team explorer changes, nor the right-mouse-button menu of the tab of the text editor. Is there any way to rename such file without having to manually open the explorer and paste the file's path?

Comment: You can add new solution folder at solution level (if the file is not in any of the projects), add your file and perform any operations

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski adding a new solutions seems like a very weird workaround. Copying the path to explorer seems better.